# How to Copy Transform.rotation over Network (byte[]) in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, quaternions

So I have this problem

I want to have indentical object rotation on client and on server. But somehow it won't work.
client:

```
        byte[] buff = new byte[sizeof(float) * 3];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(Object.eulerAngles.x), 0, buff, 0 * sizeof(float), sizeof(float));
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(Object.eulerAngles.y), 0, buff, 1 * sizeof(float), sizeof(float));
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(Object.eulerAngles.z), 0, buff, 2 * sizeof(float), sizeof(float));
```

server:

```
    vect.x = BitConverter.ToSingle(msg.Array, msg.Array.Length - 3 * sizeof(float));
    vect.y = BitConverter.ToSingle(msg.Array, msg.Array.Length - 2 * sizeof(float));
    vect.z = BitConverter.ToSingle(msg.Array, msg.Array.Length - sizeof(float));

    q = Quaternion.Euler(vect);
    Debug.Log(q);
    TargetObject_Transform.rotation = q;
```

Comment: Seems like a typo. Shouldn't it be `msgArray.Length - 1 - (1,2, or 3) * sizeof(float)` ? Why not just express it the same way it's done in `BlockCopy` calls, as `(0, 1, or 2) * sizeof(float)`?

Comment: rot.x = BitConverter.ToSingle(msg, offset * sizeof(float) + 0 * sizeof(float));

// this is how I formated as I got it to work

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out..

I didn't take into account that my client message size was 1024 bytes and such the fact that I took the mytes out of the arrays .Lenght - minus the position was actually far off from the actual position of the bytes I wanted. Once I got the bytes from the correct place. Everything worked well